# Jenkins - Move View into View

Tags: view, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have 3 views and want to integrate them in one single view so that they become sub folders in this one view.

How can I do this? Or do I have to make a view and then add and configure these views by hand again?

Answer (score -1):

Look into [Nested View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nested+View+Plugin).

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question (which is one I also have) was about how to take three existing views and nest them under a new view (I'm already using the NVP). Is this something done in config.xml?